# Which ORM should I use for Node.js Express and Postgres

Tags: node.js

I have been looking around an architecture for my backend services that needs to be developed using open source technology.

A Node JS with Express is an option for REST-API.

However, what about the middle tier between express controllers and Postgres SQL Server?

I am keen to make this middle tier as an ORM connecting with SQL 
The main question that I have in my mind is which ORM I should be using with NODE JS Express.

I have been fiddling around various options, and everyone gives their own opinion with some limitation within.

There are three frameworks that I have got to know during the research:

- http://bookshelfjs.org/
- Node-ORM2
- http://sequelizejs.com/

What is my need:

1. An ORM that support what RDMS has to offer.
2. It should support Postgres.
3. Minimal learning curve.
4. Easy to integrate with Node/ Express
5. Good documentations and community support.
6. At some point I will be using Memcached (http://memcached.org/) that it should be compatible with.

[image]

What is your thoughts on your selection?

Comment: I'm not sure about the last point, but sequelizejs seems to satisfy all o the rest. I had used it in a project when I was starting off with NodeJS (I am a Django guy mostly). A very good thing about sequelizejs is that it supports a lot of dbms's

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a lot of requirements.

You can try [pgo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pgo), which is a node.js postgresql dedicatd ORM.
It doesn't meet all of your requirements, but you can evaluate it.

Comment: A good start would be to list the requirements met by your answer.